# Referring to buttons by their tag but not in its action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

So, I'm fairly new to this.
Anyway, I have about 36 buttons connected to one action which references them by their `tag`. Later in the application, when a button that is not one the 36 is pressed, I want to disable the 36 buttons. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Use their `enabled` property.

Since they have tags, you can reference each one with `[self.view viewWithTag:tag]`

So for example let's say the tags are 1 thru 36. Then:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 37; i++)
     [[self.view viewWithTag:i] setEnabled:NO];
```

If you want to omit a particular button from being disabled you'll need to modify that logic. I'm just showing the general idea.

Comment: I have `[[self.view viewWithTag:11] enabled:FALSE];` but it gives me the error "Instance method '-enabled' not found (return type defaults to 'id')"

Comment: `viewWithTag` returns a `UIView` which does not have the `enabled` method.  If you want to do that, make sure your view implements the `enabled` selector, and send it... or if you know for sure its type, cast it directly to the proper type.

Comment: @JodyHagins Sorry, but I don't actually know how to do either of those

Comment: @JodyHagins Why not tell him he means `setEnabled:`? We are here to help, mostly...

Comment: You should not send a message to an object unless you know it supports the message.  `if ([view respondsToSelector:@selector(setEnabled:)]) { [view setEnabled:NO]; }`

Comment: But we know for a fact these are buttons.

Comment: Actually, I have a new problem. The tags don't increase by 1 because they correspond to images. Anyway, I'm using this instead: `    NSInteger squares[] = {11,21,31,41,51,61,12,22,32,42,52,62,13,23,33,43,53,63,14,24,34,44,54,64,15,25,35,45,55,65,16,26,36,46,56,66}; [[self.view viewWithTag:(squares[i])] setEnabled:NO];`

But this makes the whole view unusable, including a UITextField and a different UIButton with the tag 99. Why?

Comment: You know, it really would be better if you had a better way to refer to these buttons. You should learn about outlets, and outlet collections; with an outlet collection you would have an NSArray referring to the buttons themselves.

Comment: I fear it may be a bit late for that

Comment: Well, I don't see why. You can have tags *and* outlets, you know. But in any case it's impossible to discuss this in the comments because you can't format your code. So perhaps it would be best to ask a whole new question at this point.